# Proving $f(x)$ has a derivative

Tags: derivatives

Assume that at $x = c$ the function has a derivative.

How to prove the following,

$$\lim_{h\to 0}  \frac{f(c+3h)-f(c-h)}{h} = 4f'(c)$$

I substituted the values $h \to 0$ right away and it became $\infty$ in LHS. When I try to find the derivative, do we have to apply the derivative rule to all of the $f(x)$ function in the given equation?.

Comment: Actually substituting  $h=0$ makes the left hand side $\frac00$ so that is not a helpful step

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. What do you actually know? Do you know that the limit in the LHS exists, and you should prove that this implies that the function is differentiable, and that the limit is $4f'(c)$? Because, if you already know that LHS equals $4f'(c)$, then it is assumed $f'(c)$ exists already. Please clarify.

Comment: i want prove it and the function has a derivative at x=c.

Comment: You should state your assumptions and what you want to prove in such a manner that the reader knows which is which. I know which is which in this case, but only because I know the result to begin with.

Comment: The edit makes things more opaque (less clear than before). Start by saying something like this: "Assuming the derivative of $f$ at $x=c$ exists, I want to prove that [insert displayed limit here]. In trying to show this, I tried substituting the values ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\frac{f(c+3h)-f(c-h)}{h} = 3\cdot\frac{f(c+3h)-f(c)}{3h} + \frac{f(c)-f(c-h)}{h}
$$